# why doesn't ng-show remove class ng-hide

Tags: angularjs

I need to show and hide a div. I do it by putting true of false values into the ng-show

```
<div  class="drawingToolPropertie" ng-show="{{ drawingMods.settingRoof}}">


<div  class="drawingToolPropertie" ng-show="{{ drawingMods.settingObs}}">
```

But this is what i get:

```
<div id="roofPropertie" class="drawingToolPropertie ng-hide" ng-hide="true">
<div id="ObstaclePropertie" class="drawingToolPropertie ng-hide" ng-hide="false">
```

values chage but that ng-hide class stays and as result those divs are always hidden. How do i fix this ? Why is this working like this ? I'm not using jquery.

Comment: It is working as it should. `ng-show` is nothing more than sugar for negating `ng-hide`. The value of `ng-hide` attribute is what matters.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

ng-show/ng-hide uses no double brackets

```
ng-show="drawingMods.settingRoof"
```